# Set axis fields from controller- Extjs4 charts

Tags: charts, extjs4, extjs-mvc

How can I dynamically set axis and series fields of ExtJs4 Chart? I have a combobox which contains all attributes of a store using which user can select X-Axis and Y-Axis fields of a line chart. So whenever user changes selection I have to change the fields of chart from controller.

Thanks

Comment: What does your code currently look like and what problems are you having implementing this? Any error messages etc?

Comment: Right now I have implemented a bar chart where the axes fields are manually set. But I don't want to set this manually. Whenever user selects any attribute from combobox I have to build the chart using those attributes as axes fields. For ex: I have a store with following attributes - name,age,domain,country,salary,monthly_spend.  user can select any 2 of these.(salary vs monthly_spend for instance) Then I want to build the chart. How do I set the fields of chart from controller?